# Use one class more than once in TestNG

Tags: java, testing, selenium, testng

There is and example of structure in my test running using TestNG and Selenium:

```
<test>
      <classes>

          <class name="com.pou.MyTest">
                  <methods>
             // params here
             <include name="myMethodOne" />
          </methods>
          </class>

          <class name="com.pou.MyTest">
                  <methods>
             // params here
             <include name="myMethodTwo" />
          </methods>
          </class> 

      </classes>
</test>
```

After running this suite I recive an error:

> org.testng.TestNGException: No free nodes found in:[DynamicGraph

I was told that it is caused by calling the same method twice in one

Now the question is: Can I use the same class twice in one test?

I'll also add that for some reasons I need to have it in one test, so spliting it to two different tests is not the approach I need.

Answer (score -1):

Consider using a `@DataProvider` instead, classes can only appear once in each test tag.

Comment: DataProvider cannot be used here. Why should he use DataProvider if the methods he is executing are different??